# Why have nothing to override, but still can put @Override without syntax error?

Tags: java, java-17

I am using Java language level 17 on JDK 19. I have

```java
package ocp17.ch07;

public record BeardedDragon(boolean fun) {
    
    @Override
    public boolean fun() {
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Why have nothing to override, but still can put `@Override` without syntax error?

Comment: You've got a tag of `java-17` but you're talking about JDK19... which is it? (Or has Java done something "interesting" with language versions that I'm not aware of? I wouldn't rule that out...)

Comment: I revised my question. JDK 19, and set Java language level is 17.

Comment: Why would it be a syntax error? It is perfectly legal to put an annotation there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are indeed overriding the `fun` method (which is bad in this case<sup>1</sup>). With Java records, the accessor name (which it automatically gives for you) doesn't have the `get` prefix - it is `fun()` and not `getFun()` or `isFun()`.

The [Record Members section of JLS states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.3)

> Furthermore, for each record component, a record class has a method with the same name as the record component and an empty formal parameter list. This method, which is declared explicitly or implicitly, is known as an accessor method.

The [Records JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) also says,

> The meaning of the @Override annotation was extended to include the case where the annotated method is an explicitly declared accessor method for a record component.

*@Sweeper's answer points to the appropriate section of JLS for this*

So whatever you've done now counts as overriding.

---

<sup>1</sup> Why is it bad?

Let's say you have an instance of `BeardedDragon` like,

```
BeardedDragon dragon = new BeardedDragon(true);
if (dragon.fun()) {
     System.out.println("Yay!!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Dang it.. It was supposed to be fun");
}
```

It will return *false* when you call `fun()`. I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Also, it violates the below requirement from the JLS.

> Consider a record class R that has components c1, ..., cn, and an
> implicitly declared accessor method for every component, and an
> implicitly declared equals method. If an instance r1 of R is copied in
> the following way:
>
> R r2 = new R(r1.c1(), r1.c2(), ..., r1.cn());
>
> then, assuming r1 is not the null reference, it is always the case
> that the expression r1.equals(r2) will evaluate to true. Explicitly
> declared accessor methods and equals methods should respect this
> invariant. It is not generally possible for a compiler to check
> whether explicitly declared methods respect the invariant.

Using the example from @Johannes Kuhn (from the comments).

```
var b1 = new BeardedDragon(true); 
var b2 = new BeardedDragon(b1.fun()); 
assert b1.equals(b2); // This will fail
```

Comment: Correct!   The JLS states: *" Furthermore, for each record component, a record class has a method with the same name as the record component and an empty formal parameter list. This method, which is declared explicitly or implicitly, is known as an accessor method."*

Comment: Yes. Maybe you could add that those methods are auto-generated by the compiler, and you're overriding *those*. So while it's not obvious, you're still overriding.

Comment: @Thiyagu - At this stage it is better to quote JLS 17 rather than the JEP.  Records are no longer a preview feature, so JLS is now the definitive source of information.

Comment: @StephenC Makes sense. Will update my answer. Btw the JEP I've linked is part of the Java 16 release. Anyway I agree that quoting from JLS is better

Comment: The requirement is: `var b1 = new BeardedDragon(...); var b2 = new BeardedDragon(b1.fun(); assert b1.equals(b2);`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn My last example is unrelated to the requirement excerpt.

Comment: My point is: It does not violate the requirement that you did quote. Or your example doesn't show that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn The way I wrote it might have been confusing. I've updated it. I was trying to bring out two points.

Comment: Why do they even allow you to override the record methods? The generated methods could implicitly final. What's the use-case?

Comment: @Michael Because an accessor may want to make a defensive copy for mutable components (such as arrays, or mutable collections) before returning it to the caller.  For a record with mutable components (e.g., an ArrayList), there are two valid but different sets of semantics the record might want to implement, and both should be expressible.

Answer (score 16):

There *is* something to override, namely the accessor for the record component `fun`. That is also a method called `fun`. Though, I agree that this is not the same kind of "override" as overriding a method in a superclass, which is how `@Override` is most often used for.

The [`@Override` section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4) of the spec talks about this.

> The clause about a record class is due to the special meaning of
> @Override in a record declaration. Namely, it can be used to specify
> that a method declaration is an accessor method for a record
> component. Consider the following record declaration:
>
> ```
> record Roo(int x) {
>     @Override
>     public int x() {
>         return Math.abs(x);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The use of @Override on the accessor method int x() ensures that if
> the record component x is modified or removed, then the corresponding
> accessor method must be modified or removed too.

Comment: Quick question - I'll read the jls later :) - does this effectively generate a new class (like `@Override` on an enum value's method ends up in a new subclass of the enum being generated)?

Comment: @ernest_k No. The spec says it's a "special meaning", so it is a "hardcoded" construct just for record components. Section 8.10 (records) doesn't mention any anonymous classes like the one in the enum section, either.